# Android - How to retrieve data from multiple nodes and display it in a Single list?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from multiple nodes and store them in a Single List. I am able to do that but the problem is data is getting duplicated if I remove `list.clear();` in function `getTeam2()`.

Here is the Screenshot of the Database.

[image]

**Here is The Code**

```
 databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Teams")
            .child(team1).child("Players");

    databaseReference.orderByChild("playertype").equalTo("Wk")
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    mList.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Player player = dataSnapshot.getValue(Player.class);
                        mList.add(player);
                        getTeam2(mList);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
    return view;
}

private void getTeam2(final List<Player> mList) {
    DatabaseReference team = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Teams")
            .child(team2).child("Players");
    team.orderByChild("playertype").equalTo("Wk")
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Player player = dataSnapshot.getValue(Player.class);
                        mList.add(player);
                        bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                    adapter = new PlayerAdapter(getContext(), WKFragement.this.mList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
}
```

If I use `list.clear();` in `team2` function then it only displays the members of team2.

What changes should I make?

Comment: Are there the same players, in both locations?

Comment: You'll need to store the keys of the players for each team, so that instead of `mList.clear();` you can remove only the players of the team that was updated.

Comment: @AlexMamo No, There are different players in each team.

Comment: Can you please edit the question and add the database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have already store players in keys. And I have shared a screenshot of the database.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have shared a screenshot of the Database

Comment: Your database nodes don't match those in your code.